# How to consume a rest service with angularJs from different project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest

I created a project which contains spring rest service that provides json format and angularJS Client which consumes the service and that work perfectly. Now I create another project which contains just the client (angularjs and html views) but I don't know how to access my rest service from this project. 
This is what I have done :

```
 angular.module('workflowService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Demande', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/rest/employee/:id', {}, {
            'save': {method:'PUT'}
        });
    });


function EmployeeListController($scope, $location, Employee) {
$scope.employees = Employee.query();
$scope.gotoEmployeeNewPage = function () {
    $location.path("/employee/new");
};
$scope.deleteEmployee = function (employee) {
    employee.$delete({'id':employee.idEmp}, function () {
        $location.path('/');
    });
};
}
```

Any help please ?

Comment: We can consume the call by changing the url in the service for example http://localhost/firstProject/edit/48 for first project use http://localhost/secondProject/edit/48 for second project. configure that in angular configuration file

Comment: I tried that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to consume the REST service that your Spring back-end is providing. You should use the built-in Angular [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service to make calls to your back-end.

Make sure [CORS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) is enabled on your back-end to allow different origins to make requests.